# Hook in Spring Boot to plug in own RabbitMQ client?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm thinking of developing a simulation of RabbitMQ that can be used in unit tests where it is not possible to start up an entire RabbitMQ server or not possible to connect to one. This RabbitMQ simulation would obviously have the same API as the RabbitMQ Java client. Question is now how to plug in this API of the RabbitMQ simulation into Spring Boot instead of the original one from RabbitMQ. Is there some hook in Spring Boot so that this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to simulate RabbitMQ.

Some people have has some success using an embedded Apache QPID server running amqp 0.9.1.

However, it doesn't support any RabbitMQ extensions, if you are using those.

You'd be better off using something like TestContainers.

https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/rabbitmq/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see your point, but I'm looking for something lightweight similar to flapdoodle for mongoldb. As I just saw they managed to find some way to hook their library into the Spring Boot calling mechanism. Maybe I can find the way how to do this from looking at their approach.

Comment: There is a very basic emulator in `spring-rabbit-test`, but it doesn't have much capability yet; it might be a good starting point and if you decide to enhance it, consider contributing. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#test-template

Comment: This sounds cool with enhancing spring-rabbit-test. Will do some work and send a pull request ;-). Do I have to use some specific Java version?